# Java VM becomes unresponsive after Jetty smoke test on EC2, one core on 100%

Tags: java, jvm, amazon-ec2, jetty

We are running some smoke tests on our EC2 systems and occasionally the VM becomes completely unresponsive while it makes 1 core spin on 100%, all other cores are at 0% at this point. It does not allow further connections (RMI, JMX, HTTP requests to Jetty, all fail).

Info :

- High-CPU Extra Large Instance (instance type c1.xlarge)
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)

Has anyone experience something like this before? Any information would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I assume you have tried this on a local system and it only occurs on an EC2 system?

Comment: What does a thread dump say? Do `ps -ef | grep java` and then `kill -QUIT <pid>` where <pid> is the process ID of your java process.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, correct, load tests on other machines are fine, even under even higher load than we're putting on the EC2 instances. Also note that it's pretty random.

Comment: @Jonathan. We did that but it's ~1100 threads of data so that's going to be a bit hard to add to this. Should I look for anything specific?

Comment: Try doing 3 of them a minute or so apart, and run them through Samurai (http://yusuke.homeip.net/samurai/en/index.html) to get a picture of what threads are doing work rather than locked/waiting. You might also have a look at `-verbose:gc` logs to see if the garbage collector is chewing away.

Comment: Is your EC2 system windows or linux?

Comment: @Sean Linux, ubuntu 10.0.4 iirc

Comment: @Jonathan, we'll do that

Comment: use the top command in linux, in combination with the thread dump to identify the exact threads causing high CPU usage. see this article for more info http://blogs.manageengine.com/appmanager/2011/02/09/identify-java-code-consuming-high-cpu-in-linux-linking-jvm-thread-and-linux-pid

Comment: @Sean, thanks, I'll go and test that tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found the issue. We noticed that some instances in our cluster always produced the problem and some never did. Apparently the issue is unique to instances that run more recent CPU versions combined with slightly outdated kernels.

The issue is explained in full here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/727459

As the running time increases the spikes shown in the graph below become longer and longer, possible due to time shift and at some point it'll spin the one core for a long time.

Cpu usage graphs. Affected instance versus unaffected:

[image: Cpu usage graphs. Affected instance versus unaffected]

The issue has been fixed recently so a kernel update fixed this issue for us.

Comment: does this happen on Centos?

Answer (score 0):

I have run through this problem before with Jetty (although the same experience could be made with any Java process), and it occurs when you do not give enough memory to the JVM : all your resources are actually used by the garbage collector which walks through the object graph in order to reclaim unreferenced ones. I you wait long enough (it sometimes took several minutes in my case), you should see the JVM crash on an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Hi jpountz. The JVM is has plenty of heap left at the time when it starts spinning the cores if i recall correctly. I'll double check

Comment: We verified that it's not the GC that's spinning. We only have a few young garbage collects, no full attempts.

Comment: Have you tried waiting for a few minutes (or hours if necessary) to see if the process finally crashes? The fact that other JVM services do not respond anymore makes garbage collection a good candidate for your problem (as full GC triggered when the heap size reaches its limit need to "stop the world"). Does this problem occur on startup or after you trigger a special operation which might eat all your memory?